# Hibernate Optimistic Locking Exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, jakarta-ee

I am getting the below error in my WebApp :

`Handling an unexpected exception in webApp:
     - javax.servlet.error.status_code = 500
     - javax.servlet.error.exception_type = class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException
     - javax.servlet.error.message = Object of class [domain.entity.common.dataEntity] with identifier [110837262]: optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [domain.entity.common.dataEntity`

I am not sure why this error occurs and it occurs in the below line.

```
SpecEntity specTemp = this.persistService.merge(specTemp);
```

Can someone please help here ..

Answer (score 11):

In this scenario, the `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException` exception as it indicates happened when you tried to call `merge` on an `entity` (specTaskTemp) that was already updated in the mean time by another transaction.

If you look at `SpecEntity` class you must have defined `@Version` column. That will be used by the hibernate to check if the entity that you are merging is older than the one in the database.

Sample flow:

1. Transaction T1 loads `SpecEntity` entity that has version column value as
2. Transaction T2 loads the same `SpecEntity` with the version value 1.
3. T2 makes some changes to this entity and updates the database and so the version value becomes 2.
4. Subsequently T1 tries to update the entity.
5. Hibernate checks if the version in the entity (i.e., 1) is same as that of value in the database (which is updated to 2).
6. And when it finds the mismatch it throws `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException`.

Depending on your use case, you can either reload the updated `entity` from the database and show the `updated data` to the user so that user can decide what to do next.

Or if you want to continue overwriting the data in the database with data in the `specTaskTemp` entity, you can get the latest version of this entity from the database, copy its version value to the `specTaskTemp` entity and then invoke the `merge` call.

Comment: Thanks or the reply.. I wanted to know things like .. why does it throw error on GenDataEntity as GenDataEntity extends SpecEntity ..  Does this happen if there is merge or persist in the same session for SpecEntity .. Can we track the stale object by its ID- 110837262  in the database ..

Comment: @Teena Not sure if I can answer that without looking at your domain model and the flow of your app. Now since you know the crux of the problem and when this exception could happen, you can enable show_SQL property and see what exact sequence of events is causing the problem.